# Confused with accessing malloc memory (Uninitialized)

Tags: c, malloc

Declaring simple struct:

```
struct s {
    char* addr;
};

s *ips;
```

Now allocating that struct array memory

```
num = 5
ips = (r *) malloc(num * sizeof(r));
```

I know malloc just allocates memory, and don't initialize, there could be garbage values.

Now I wonder if I don't initialize one, and try to access what would happen?

```
//Init for 4 of them
for(int i = 0; i < num-1; i++)
    ips[i].addr = strdup("123");

//Accessing un-initialize one:
if(ips[4].addr) {
    printf("Accessing uninitialize one and lets say freeing!!!");
    free(ips[4].addr);
}
```

Ideal should not be going into this for loop. But then I think because of garbage value it may be. I'm not sure!

Comment: Congratulations! You have asked the 1,000,000th "what happens when I invoke undefined behavior?" question!  Your free copy of the C standard is in the mail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: As long as you write code that does not compile you should be safe.

Comment: works really well with sizeof(r) instead of s :)

Comment: Don't typecast malloc() return address

Answer (score 1):

What will happen will be unpredictable as you can not know what the memory contained. You should either use `calloc` instead of `malloc`, or `memset` the memory after calling `malloc`.

Personally I prefer to use `calloc` as it saves a line of code and makes it a little easier to read your code later.

Comment: Neither `calloc` nor `memset` is guaranteed to set pointers to null, or floating-point objects to `0.0`.

Comment: @Keith Thompson  Your assertion that `calloc()` does not guarantee NULL or 0.0, is that although memory is zero filled, NULL and 0.0 _may_ not be made up of just zero bits?  Or is there something else?

Comment: @chux: That's it. On most common implementations, both null pointers and floating-point `0.0` *are* represented as all-bits-zero, but the C standard doesn't guarantee it. If you're going to write code that depends on that assumption, I suggest at least making the assumption explicit. (I prefer not to depend on it; for example, `const foo_t foo_zero = { 0 };` gives you an object of type `foo_t` with all members set to zero (integer 0, floating 0.0, null pointer, ...).

Comment: @KeithThompson - Thanks, I was not aware of that, but doesn't the IEEE-754 standard cover the storage format? AFAIK this covers the binary representation, so if the compiler supports IEEE-754 (which most do these days) this should not be an issue.

Comment: @Geoffrey: I think so, but C doesn't require IEEE-754 compliance. The fewer assumptions you make, the fewer things you have to think about when tracking down an inevitable error.

Answer (score 1):

**Initialize your variables.**

Without initialization - all bets are off.
`ips[4].addr`, as you *know*, is uninitialized.  So using:

```
// Various code
...
if(ips[4].addr) {
```

is a convoluted way of simple asking what does the following do?

```
int i;
if (i) {
```

The value of `i` could be the same every time you run the program.  If could be different.  There is no ideal of what should happen.  It is simple undefined behavior (UB).